# Event based time series data in a Graph database(OrientDB)

Tags: database, oop, orientdb, graph-databases

I am working on a school project to rate user's coding skills. The DB architecture I am designing has some logical inconsistencies.

To sum up the question: How do I design a graph database to accommodate events as a property of a class instead of a new node?

**Detailed problem and some background**

I am designing a database where I am keeping track of *Users code submissions*. Each of his submission is tagged with some metadata like `python` `machine learning` `HTML` etc.

The db is composed of three elements:

1. **User**
2. **Coding-Tags** a.k.a *CT*
3. **User's *Skills*** which is a weighted collection of all the *CT* he has been associated with till now.

Following are the functionalities expected of DB:

1. It should have a graphical representation of connections in *CT*.

   - For example   [image: Knowledge graph]
   - The relationship they share is a simple *Related* relationship. The edges of the graphs would be defined accordingly.
2. A record of every *CT* a user earns (via his submissions) must be stored with the time stamp.
3. Weights of User *Skill* is a simple count of a particular *CT* earned by the user.

   - So the *Skill*'s entity should look something like this:
     [image: Skill-User relationship]
4. Every new entry in *Skill* should be an event of a user learning something new.

In the present architecture I have a *User* class which inherits a *Skill* class. And a *Skill* class is connected with *CT*'s.

Every time a user earns a *CT* a new edge is created between that *skill* node and *CT*. Because there is no datatype array or a list where I can just append the dates. Making it extremely inefficient. Instead of the above graph, the current looks something like this:
[image]

It also breaks OOP's because I want timestamp to be a property of the *skill* class. The rationale behind this is that a *skill* is a collection of *CT*'s earned. Earning a skill is an event and WHEN it's being earned would be a property of *skill* instead of an edge.

I can also create a new node for each skill earned but I think it'll introduce redundancy in the graph.

Comment: Hey.. I have couple of questions.. 1) for point 3 mentioned above, you display 3 different dates for same weight 3.... does the weight doesn't change for each date..... 2) for point 4 above, I can see 3 edges with different date connected to Python node.. what data changes between these dates, to record which, we need 3 different edges?

Comment: 1) Right now it's a linear increase, for every new date the weight updates by 1. 2)  I'm not sure how to answer this, but I'll try. The data doesn't change, we add new edge between the user and the CT everytime the user earns a CT. The weight will be calculated by counting the number of nodes. Which i think is a poor way of doing this.

Comment: Hi, what version are you using? Thx

Comment: I am using v3.0.6